# Change description of my Jetpack facebook shared links

Tags: links, title, description, plugin-jetpack

When I try to share a link from my WordPress site on facebook using the Jetpack Sharing Settings the link shows up like this:

```
(My Featured image picture here)

Put a hat on yo’ baby! | Trendz with Trina

http://www.trendzwithtrina.com/2012/02/0...

You may use these HTML tags and attributes: < a href="" title=""> < abbr title=""> < acronym title=""> < b> < blockquote cite=""> < cite> < code> < del datetime=""> < em> <i> < q cite=""> < strike> < strong>
```

How do I get rid of the "you may use blah blah blah" and have a description of my site or the post?

Comment: You should really use the plugin specific support forums on wordpress.org for this.

Comment: [Jetpack support forum at wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/tags/jetpack?forum_id=10)

Answer (score 3):

This part comes from the function [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) which is called by your theme, probably in `comments.php`:

```
'comment_notes_after'  => '<p class="form-allowed-tags">' 
    . sprintf( __( 
    'You may use these <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> tags 
    and attributes: %s' ), ' <code>' . allowed_tags() . '</code>' ) 
    . '</p>',
```

You can filter it out with a simple plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Remove Markup Notice on Comment Form
*/
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse_41181_remove_markup_notice', 10, 1 );

function wpse_41181_remove_markup_notice( $strings )
{
    $strings['comment_notes_after'] = '';
    return $strings;
}
```

How you get a better description … I don’t know. I’m sure there is a FAQ for that available. Aren’t there settings in `/wp-admin/` for this module?